# Custom Code into the Standard DotNetNuke Login?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, dotnetnuke, login-control

Where can I find the function that handles the login for DNN? I would like to add custom features to the login and I don't see the function in Login.ascx.vb (unless I missed it).

There is a  tag and a  tag that forms the login. I figure one of these has the actual "Login" button, but I cannot seem to figure out where they're coming from.

Here is as far as I've found where the login is located

```
                <DNN:DNNTabStrip 
                ID="tsLogin" 
                runat="server" 
                TabRenderMode="All"
                CssTabContainer="LoginTabGroup"
                CssContentContainer="LoginContainerGroup" 
                DefaultContainerCssClass="LoginContainer"
                DefaultLabel-CssClass="LoginTab"
                DefaultLabel-CssClassHover="LoginTabHover"
                DefaultLabel-CssClassSelected="LoginTabSelected" 
                visible="false" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlLoginContainer" runat="server" style="text-align:left" CssClass="LoginPanel" Visible="false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the /desktopmodules/AuthenticationServices directory. The out-of-the-box login control should be coming from DNN/Login.ascx.

You should be able to add user controls to that file.